# Parsing large text to textfield, how to set view position on beginning of text

Tags: java, swing

When parsing large text in this case, it is "Still loving you - Scorpions" to textfield it have look like this ->
[image] . I wanna, view start from beginning. Have also trouble with scroll bar, use JScrollPane on Jlist, and when it need scroll because large text, on initialization, it take down scroll, it be like this, what I have described for textfield.

Have this code for textfield:

```
textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setEditable(false);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(149, 33, 129, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
```

Frame, have absolute layout:

```
frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 317, 516);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add this line:

```
textfield_1.setCaretPosition ( 0 );
```

Moreover, one should not use `Absolute Positioning` as much as possible.

> Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible. A layout manager makes it easier to adjust to look-and-feel-dependent component appearances, to different font sizes, to a container's changing size, and to different locales. Layout managers also can be reused easily by other containers, as well as other programs

For more info, have a look at [Absolute Positioning Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

**EDIT 1:**

**Regarding JScrollPane**

One can achieve that in two ways:

### 1. Either use, `setPreferredSize ( ... )` on the `JScrollPane`, like:

```
myList = new JList ( listData );
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane ();
listScroller.setViewportView ( myList );
listScroller.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension ( 100, 100 ) ) ;
contentPane.add ( listScroller );
```

### 2. Or one can override, `getPreferredSize ()` for the said `JComponent`, like:

```
myList = new JList ( listData );
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane () {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
        return new Dimension ( DIMENSION, DIMENSION );
    }
};
listScroller.setViewportView ( myList );
contentPane.add ( listScroller );
```

Comment: I tried this now, and because I do not put text on initialization, i need to put every parsing time ( runtime  of program ( get text from database ) ), after that line, again this (setCaretPosition) , have any other solution, like set it just once on initialization textField?

Comment: and if you can tell me what can i do with scrolls ?

Comment: Naa, but you can keep this line, where you actually getting text for the `JTextField`. There is nothing in the question regarding the `JScrollPane`

Comment: "Have also trouble with scroll bar, use JScrollPane on Jlist, and when it need scroll because large text, on initialization, it take down scroll, it be like this, what I have described for textfield."

Comment: @RadijatoR: Please have a look at the latest edit. Hope this will be of some help

Comment: @RadijatoR: Do try this `listScroller.getViewport ().scrollRectToVisible ( new Rectangle ( 0, 0, DIMENSION, DIMENSION ) );`, if this is what you asking of !!!!